# What is the relationship between a NIZK protocol and a digital signature scheme?

Tags: signature, zero-knowledge-proofs, fiat-shamir

I am reading about the Fiat-Shamir heuristic to take a $\Sigma$-protocol into a non-interactive zero-knowledge proof (NIZK). I am now wondering whether there is a relationship between a NIZK proof and a digital signature scheme?

Specifically, can we take a NIZK proof obtained from applying Fiat-Shamir to a $\Sigma$-protocol and turn it into a digitial signature scheme? (Are there specific requirements for the underlying $\Sigma$-protocol?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that in *strong existential unforgeability* for
digital signatures, we want it to be the case that even after seeing many signatures under different instances, it should still not be possible to create a new signature unless you know the secret key (equivalently witness in a NIZK).

So, one can use a NIZK to design a digital signature (of knowledge), but the underlying NIZK needs to provide a more stronger version of soundness (a standard NIZK only provides soundness) that technically is known as **simulation-sound extractability**. Intuitively, *simulation-sound extractability* in NIZKs is equivalent to concept of *strong existential unforgeability*. More precisely, simulation-sound extractability implies that it is only possible to prove instances to which you know a witness, even when you have already seen a number of simulated proofs (signatures).

To sum up, a digital signature of knowledge can be designed using a NIZK that guarantees simulation-sound extractability.